# Chrome in Mac is not starting in maximised state even after trying with '--start-fullscreen' in args

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

Need my chrome to start in maximised state every time my protractor suite initialises

Have already tried updating the chrome drive with webdriver-manager update. Still no go

I'm using this in my conf.js onPrepare function

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',

```
'platform': 'ANY',
'version': 'ANY',
'chromeOptions': {
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--start-fullscreen',],
```

Right now I'm getting the message to press ^CommandF to exit full screen but the chrome is not actually in full screen

Answer (score 0):

try switching `'--start-fullscreen'` with `'--start-maximized'`

Comment: Tried that as well. Chrome launches in the same window size.
But the "exit fullscreen" message is no longer displayed at the start

Comment: For some reason browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();  worked

Comment: @ShubhAmbaly wait, I re-read your post, are you declaring the capabilities inside an `onPrepare` function? That might be causing problems? I have my capabilities and onPrepare code separate

Answer (score 0):

Try with below chrome option

`args: ['--kiosk']`

Hope it helps you

Comment: It turned my chrome headless. But not fullscreened.
I'm still the below error as the required element is not showing up on the screen
Failed: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1319, 82)

Answer (score 0):

I use these settings in my protractor-conf.js file, and it works on all type of OS : Windows, Mac, Linux etc.

```
onPrepare: function () {

browser.driver.executeScript(function () {
        return {
          width: window.screen.availWidth,
          height: window.screen.availHeight
        };
      }).then(function (result) {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(result.width, result.height);
      });

};
```